# Kernel Panic from overheating?

Tags: cpu, kernel, overheating

I believe my CPU is overheating which is causing a kernel panic and the machine reboots.  It is an Intel 3612QE.  I have changed the cpufrequtils scaling_governor to ondemand, conservative, and also powersave for testing purposes.  In ondemand, the kernel panic happens in the 70's and the computer shuts down, conservative it does not happen but CPU is in the 50-60 degree range, powersave is the coolest as expected, CPU never goes over 1.2 GHz and hovers around 50 degrees.

I have also tested with turbomode (in the BIOS settings) off which keeps the cpu from going over 2.1 Ghz.  This usually prevents the kernel panic as well.

The thing is, I have not seen the temp higher than the mid 70's, but the kernel panic still kicks in.  Shouldn't it be 87, which is what "sensors" tells me?

I believe that the CPU heatsink is not ideal, but it is not really based on facts, just from the testing I just described.  It is a custom heatsink.

Is there a way to catch this thermal trip before it goes to the kernel?  Also, is there a way to be sure the kernel panic is from overheating?  I have been unable to capture the kernel panic output so far, so I only get a glimpse of it.

EDIT:
There is an "active" thermal trigger at 71 degrees (cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/trip_point_1_temp), coincidence?  Maybe it is trying to start a fan that is not connected?  The only fan is right on the CPU heatsink and is on full blast all the time.

Here is the MCELOG from the kernel panic:

```
mcelog: mcelog read: No such device
Hardware event. This is not a software error.
MCE 0
CPU 0 BANK 4
TIME 1418932337 Thu Dec 18 14:52:17 2014
MCG status:
MCi status:
Uncorrected error
Error enabled
Processor context corrupt
MCA: Internal unclassified error: 402
Running trigger `unknown-error-trigger'
STATUS b200000000100402 MCGSTATUS 0
MCGCAP c09 APICID 0 SOCKETID 0
CPUID Vendor Intel Family 6 Model 58
```

Comment: If your CPU was overheating your computer would be shutting itself down.

Comment: The Kernel Panic happens and then the computer shuts down.

Comment: usually a temperature related power off is just that, a blackscreen shutdown. The OS doesn't even know its about to happen. just the next second it is off. Second, that chip is 35Watt (so you should not be reaching 70C easily unless you have a bad or poorly installed heatsink), and the TJMax is 105 degrees C, so it should have no trouble operating at 70+. check your BIOS setting to see what temp the box is configured to shut down at. Also, to test your heatsink, perform a task that heats it up, and watch how quickly the temp falls. CPUs heat fast and cool fast if your heatsink is working.

Comment: This is all being tested while running a processor intensive task.  Heats up and cools fast, within seconds.  I checked in the BIOS, but I don't see anything with a temperature setting on it.  There are a couple config options in Turbo Mode that I don't understand like: Turbo Mode Power Limit Lock, Long Power Limit, Long Power Limit Time, Short Power Limit, IA Current Limit, IGFX Current Limit.

Comment: Does it still kernel panic with the powersave (slowest freq) governor, and it stays below 50C, after running for a few hours? And are you certain that `sensors` is reporting the actual temps (are they significantly different in bios, maybe too slow to reboot & check reliably). - Probably not an overheating -> shutdown, but could be heat-related hardware problem. --- What's the kernel panic anyway? Nothing in any logs about it?

Comment: It does not panic in powersave and stays around 50C after running for a few hours.  I am not sure that sensors is reporting actual temps, but I don't have any easy way to confirm that at the moment.  Rebooting would take too long.  I haven't seen anything related to the kernel panic in the logs.  It is something about a machine error, I only see it for a few seconds before the machine reboots.